# Python class instance without variable assignment

Tags: python, class, memory

If I create an instance of a class without assigning it to a variable will it occupy memory every time I run the code? Or does the memory free up after the line of code containing the instance is executed?

For example:

```
class TestClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Moto = "Moto"
    def printIt(self):
        print self.Moto
```

So if I use it like this:

```
TestClass().printIt()
```

Does it occupy more and more memory every time the line is executed?

Comment: Do you really have to ? Shouldn't `printIt` be a static method ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No, the instance will be automatically garbage collected.** The exact mechanism depends on the Python implementation. CPython uses reference counting and will free the instance at the end of `TestClass().printIt()`.

If, however, you were to retain one or more references to the newly constructed object, the object would be kept alive for as long as it's being referenced.

Comment: and (you might also mention) if the object holds a reference to itself directly or indirectly then it will be garbage collected eventually but even in CPython it won't be cleaned up immediately.

Answer (score 2):

No, the object will be garbage collected immediately, even though *when* the garbage collector "kicks in" and actually free the object is implementation dependent.

If we look at the CPython source code, we can see that the object is deallocated immediately:

```
/* Include/object.h */
#define Py_DECREF(op)                                   \
    do {                                                \
        if (_Py_DEC_REFTOTAL  _Py_REF_DEBUG_COMMA       \
        --((PyObject*)(op))->ob_refcnt != 0)            \
            _Py_CHECK_REFCNT(op)                        \
        else                                            \
        _Py_Dealloc((PyObject *)(op));                  \
    } while (0)
```

And `_Py_Dealloc` is defined as:

```
#define _Py_Dealloc(op) (                               \
    _Py_INC_TPFREES(op) _Py_COUNT_ALLOCS_COMMA          \
    (*Py_TYPE(op)->tp_dealloc)((PyObject *)(op)))
#endif /* !Py_TRACE_REFS */
```

So as you can see The `tp_dealloc` slot, which has the responsibility to free the memory is called directly.

Other implementations, like PyPy, IronPython or Jython may not free the memory immediatly, this could lead to a *termporary* increase in the memory usage.

In particular I believe in Jython everything depends on the Java garbage collector, which is not guaranteed to free the memory as soon as it can. Even calling `System.gc()` is a mere suggestion for the garbage collector but it does not force it to free the memory.

Comment: Yes, jython is wholly dependant on the Java GC.